# How to determine what websites or local applications are using JVM/JRE

Tags: windows, java

We run a large Windows shop -- tens of thousands of workstations. Most have a version of the Sun/Oracle Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed.

With all the security issues around the JVM, we'd like to better determine what folks are using Java for on our PCs. So for example, we'd be interested in better knowing the local Windows applications that invoke the JVM for some functionality or understanding the web sites which include Java that cause the JVM plugin to fire off.

Does anyone have experience or good ideas on how to find this kind of information out? For example, is there some way to configure the JVM to log the application that invoked it or what web sites it's interacting with? Or is information like this already somewhere like the event log?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Windows administrator but I believe you could invoke WMIC.exe remotely and get information about what Java process are currently running on remote systems.  Also, you may be able to remotely access a Registry on domain member machines.

Comment: Thanks. We have SCCM in place and have been tracking whether or not Java's being used on our workstations, so we definitely can remove it from workstations that don't need it. The trouble we're having is determining what the folks who are using Java are actually using it for. We were hoping that there was a way to log this information so that we could gather it up later.

Comment: Not that I have ever heard of.  I don't think there is such a thing.  All you can do is monitor the systems using Windows tools.  With WMIC you can get the full execution path (and args) of a Java program (if you know what the system PATH is).